# Make code working in mobile version

Tags: php, html, wordpress, mobile

This code allow to limit a characters in search area and works good in desktop version, but not in mobile one. How to make it working in mobile version too?

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="woocommerce-product-search" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/'  ) ); ?>">
<label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"><?php _e( '', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
<input pattern=".{17,}" required title="You must enter 17 characters at last, to search Car by VIN Number" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Enter VIN Number&hellip;', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
```

Comment: Please add what steps you have tried and any error messages.

Comment: I have no error message.This is Wordpress plugin for woocommerce product search by SKU.